# How to add a line break to the output of a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=UPPER($B$8)& " " &PROPER($C$8) & "& " & UPPER($B$9)& " "&PROPER($C$9))
```

I want add a line break to a cell. Current my cell looks like this:

```
SMITH John & SMITH Linda
```

But I want to display like this:

```
SMITH John & 
SMITH Linda
```

So that there is a line break after the & sign and everything is displayed in one cell. I have been Googling the answer, but I found the answer is usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that only adds a like break to the cell formula, not how it is displayed. Am I doing something wrong?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
    =UPPER($B$8)& " " & PROPER($C$8) & " &" & CHAR(10) & UPPER($B$9) & " " & PROPER($C$9)
```

and enable text wrapping in the cell with the formula:

[image: wrap text]

or

[image: simpler wrapping of text]

**EDIT#1:**

There are **four** things at issue here:

- *Text wrapping* must be enabled in the formula cell
- the column must be wide enough to prevent "accidental" line-breaks
- the `CHAR(10)` should be inserted where YOU want the line-breaks
- the row height may need to be adjusted manually

For example

```
="James" & CHAR(10)  & "Ravenswood"
```

**EDIT#2**

Of course if the cell does not contain a formula, but only typed text then using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the insertion point:

1. automatically inserts the **ASCII-10**
2. automatically turns on *Text wrapping*
3. automatically adjusts the row height

Comment: the space in CHAR(10 ) is redundant?

Comment: @kuromusha  You are correct..........the space has no effect on the formula at all.

Comment: The only important thing seems to be to ensure 'wrap text' is enabled, actually.  If 'wrap text' is disabled, Excel strips any linefeed characters and doesn't show them.

Comment: @Brian.....See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Very odd.  I'm a lifelong Excel guy.  This use of CHAR(10) makes sense, but Excel 2016 64bit is doing nothing with it, no matter the word wrap, height, width, etc.  It's treating CHAR(10) as a virtual null.  (?!)

Comment: Okay, I'm tempted to delete my lost comment, but I'll own up.  I ASSumed I had word wrap on.  (sigh)   Numb nut.  Thanks.  They say "speaking out" (or typing maybe in this case) what you're doing makes you realize your mistake   ;-)

Comment: @AMM  We all experience the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Add `CHAR(13)` (that works for me, if not works for you try char(10)) AND enable text wrapping in the cell, otherwise new line character won't have effect.

Comment: I don't understand, when I add `CHAR10`, it just gives me an error.

Comment: Did you use ` =UPPER($B$8)& " " &PROPER($C$8) & "& " & char(10) & UPPER($B$9)& " "&PROPER($C$9)) ` and get write? Which version of excel do yo use? What is the error?